# I am using apache mod rewrie to redirect http to https but now cannot connect to localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

here is my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@whereever.com
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/http
<Directory />
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/http>
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Not sure how to fix this. Any thoughts?

Comment: What error are you getting?  What is your `VirtualHost` block for port 443?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to connect to 'https://localhost/phpmyadmin'.

Alternatively you can modify your RewriteRule to include a back reference for the matched string.

```
RewriteRule /(.*) https://mysite.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following RewriteRules to accomplish redirect. This will preserve the requested URL and just change the protocol to https://

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
```